# php DOM extract links from specific table

Tags: php

In my code I want to extract all links and their text from my old website I am successful to do it but the problem is somewhere I have used `ol>li` tags and somewhere I used `ul>li` tags inside table and I have about 400 different pages I can extract all the links but I have to change `ol` to `ul` every time so the easiest and time saving way for me to extract links and their text from all pages is to define that specific `<table>` which contains links but when I define `<table>` it also extract links from all others from other tables which I don't want

Table Structure to target that contains `ol>li` or `ul>li` tags

```
<table style="width:850px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="3">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; background-color: rgb(51, 51, 204);">
            <h1>My Links</h1>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ol>
                    <li><a href="http://websitelink.com/page1.php">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://websitelink.com/page2.php">Page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://websitelink.com/page3.php">Page 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://websitelink.com/page4.php">Page 4</a></li>
                </ol>
                ...
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://websitelink.com/a.php">Page A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://websitelink.com/b.php">Page B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://websitelink.com/c.php">Page C</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://websitelink.com/d.php">Page D</a></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My Current PHP Code

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://mywebsitelink.com/pagename.html');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$oltags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ol'); // I have to change between ul and ol instead of this I can define table

foreach ($oltags as $list){
    $links =  $list->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach ($links as $href){
    $text = $href->nodeValue;
    $href = $href->getAttribute('href');
    if(!empty($text) && !empty($href)) {
    echo "Link Title:     " . $text . "       Location:     " . $href . "<br />";
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Any problem on using regex?  You can practice it with [PHP regex online](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: @Memristor I have no problem using regex

Comment: I think the question was answered already, if not let me know so i can try to help you.  By the way i tried `<ol>[.\s]*<li>[.\s]*<a href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a>` on the link i gave you and took the URL and text for each group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://mywebsitelink.com/pagename.html');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$thetags = $xpath->query('//table/tbody/tr/td/ol/li/a|//table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a');

foreach($thetags as $onetag)
{
    $links =  $onetag->getElementsByTagName('a');

    foreach ($links as $onelink){
        $text = $onelink->nodeValue;
        $href = $onelink->getAttribute('href');
        if(!empty($text) && !empty($href)) {
            echo "Link Title:     " . $text . "       Location:     " . $href . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
[...]
```

Comment: `Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in `

Comment: is it possible to fetch between `ul` or `ol` tag using this function `$oltags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ol');` like this `$oltags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ol|ul');`

Comment: thanks can you please update you answer with showing me an example of featch the links and text from the start as i am the beginner

Comment: I am getting this `Notice: Undefined variable: dom in`

Comment: works perfectly but the issue is same it fetching all links from the url instead of a specific table :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one. Here we are using `DOMDocument` and doing `DOMXPath` query over `anchors` present in `li`

> `XPath` query `//table/tbody/tr/td/ol/li/a|//table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a` here we are searching for `//table/tbody/tr/td/ol/li/a` or `//table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a` with `|` operator.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/859057)

```
$links=array();
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($string);

$domXPath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$results = $domXPath->query("//table/tbody/tr/td/ol/li/a|//table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a"); //querying domdocument
foreach($results as $result)
{
    $links[]=$result->getAttribute("href");//gathering href attribute
}
print_r($links);
```

Comment: this one was so simple but the problem is i fetches all the links from webpage i just want to target on specific table inside which i used ol or ul tags

Comment: So edit the query string and leave only ol and ul ...?

Comment: @SahilGulati I was pointing out to the OP that all he needs to do is use your answer and delete the tags he doesn't need from the xpath query.

Comment: @Rtra try my post. I have updated it. now it will work fine as you are expecting.

Comment: @SahilGulati thanks for your kind help a part of your code is used as live billions of thanks